# Something wrong with the Software center?

Tags: 16.04, software-center

I just upgraded to 16.04. I notice that the Software center loads extremely slow. And that a lot of packages aren't there. They're supposed to, but a search gives me 'No application found'.

Is that a bug or feature?

Comment: Try starting it from a commandline and add the output to your question. The extra informations might help.

Comment: In 16.04, the Software Center isn't included by default. This raises the question whether you mean the Software Center or the new application for this called "Ubuntu Software". Open a terminal and type in `ubuntu-software` or `software-center` to see which one you mean. Note that if you didn't install the package `software-center`, the application `software-center` doesn't exist.